# Programming the menu phase of a simple program

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I had a problem developing this phase of uni's project in Visual C. I was wondering if you could do me a big favor and help me solve it out.
In this phase we have to build the menu of it including this five sub-menus :

1. Continue last game...
2. Single Player
3. Options
4. Credits
5. Top Scores

Our navigation policy : Scroll through these 5 items with up and down buttons ( arrows ) 
We enter submenu with enter , and when we're in them we should come back via Enter again
Esc helps us quit the program! 

Alright! My problem is the second part, I can't come back from a submenu via Enter! 
This is my code :

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int m1(int n);
int m2(int n);
int m3(int n);
int m4(int n);
int m5(int n);
int a(int n);
char c,x,y;
int i=1;
int main(){
K: printf("-->Continue last game...\nSingle player\nOptions\nCredits\nTop scores");
    while(1){
        c=getch();
        if (c!=13&&c!=27&&c!=-32) {continue;}
        if (c==13) {a(i); L:c=getch(); if (c==13) {system("cls");goto K;} else goto L;}   
        if (c==27) {system("cls");printf("Press eny key to Exit...");y=getch();break;}
        x=getch();
        if (c==-32&&x==72&&i!=1) (i--); else if (c==-32&&x==72&&i==1) i=5;   
        if (c==-32&&x==80&&i!=5) (i++); else if (c==-32&&x==80&&i==5) i=1;
        switch (i){
            case 1:
        system("cls");
        m1(i);
        break;
        case 2:
        system("cls");
        m2(i);
        break;
        case 3:
        system("cls");
        m3(i);
        break;
        case 4:
        system("cls");
        m4(i);
        break;
        case 5:
        system("cls");
        m5(i);
        break;
        }}
        return 0;
    }
int m1(int n){
    printf("-->Continue last game...\nSingle player\nOptions\nCredits\nTop scores");
    return i;
}
int m2(int n){
    printf("Continue last game...\n-->Single player\nOptions\nCredits\nTop scores");
    return i;
}
int m3(int n){
    printf("Continue last game...\nSingle player\n-->Options\nCredits\nTop scores");
    return i;
}
int m4(int n){
    printf("Continue last game...\nSingle player\nOptions\n-->Credits\nTop scores");
    return i;
}
int m5(int n){
    printf("Continue last game...\nSingle player\nOptions\nCredits\n-->Top scores");
    return i;
}

int a(int n){
    switch (i){
    case 1:  {system("cls");printf("you've chosen \"Continue last game...\" \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n press Enter to return to main menu");} break;
    case 2: {system("cls");printf("you've chosen \"single player\" \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n press Enter to return to main menu");}break;
    case 3: {system("cls");printf("you've chosen \"Options\" \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n press Enter to return to main menu");}break;
    case 4:{system("cls");printf("you've chosen \"Options\" \n\n\n\n\n \tLord.Pooria Rajabzadeh (EiNsTEiN.co(class of 2000))\n\tProducer: Pooria on 15 dec 2011\n\n press Enter to return to main menu");}break;
    case 5: {system("cls");printf("you've chosen \"Top scores\" \n\n\n\t Pooria 100\n\tAkbar 80\n\tAli 60\n\n\n press Enter to return to main menu");}break;
    return i;}
}
```

Comment: some #defines or enums would make this easier to understand & work with, and you have a lot of `i`s where it looks like you should have `n`s (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following points:

1. You have a function that displays a list of items and lets you pick an item from the list.
2. If you call function `A()` from within function `B()`, when you finish executing the code in `A()`, then the default program flow resumes in `B()`.
3. What happens if choosing a menu item in `main()` calls another function `submenu()` that displays its own list of items? What would happen in the program flow if you finished executing `submenu()` and returned to `main()` when the user hits the Enter key)?

---

Using separate functions to represent submenus is a workable solution, but it probably isn't the best practice. There's a lot of copying and pasting to handle the menu 'mechanics' (displaying the basic menu, indicating highlighted choice, etc) in each function, which can lead to issues with fixing bugs and maintaining this code over time - if there's a bug in how one menu displays, you have to go through all the menu functions you've created and fix the bug in each one of them.

If you wanted to consolidate this down into a more compact and maintainable approach, there are some things you might want to think about:

- What you are doing is displaying a List.
- The List you're displaying is a series of Items.
- Each Item might contain a List of its own, or possibly just text to display, or even a pointer to another function.

How would you build a function to display and interact with this kind of List object?

Comment: Thanks man, Really really AWESOME! Thanks for all the time and effort you put in to write this amazing help. I Will follow your lead and I'm gonna say the result

Comment: No problem! Remember to accept an answer to your question if it's the solution to your problem.